# /users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers returning answers by other users

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

According to the description, `/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers` should return answers by the user on that particular tag.

> Returns the top 30 answers a user has posted in response to questions with the given tags.

However, what it appears to be doing is posting the top answers by any user on questions the user has asked in that tag.

[example URL](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/821/tags/battlefield-3/top-answers?key=0p65aJUHxHo0G19%2aYF272A%28%28&site=gaming)

```
{
    "items": [{
        "question_id": 37051,
        "answer_id": 37238,
        "creation_date": 1321713089,
        "last_activity_date": 1321713089,
        "score": 31,
        "is_accepted": true,
        "owner": {
            "user_id": 12,
            "display_name": "Jeff Atwood",
            "reputation": 5238,
            "user_type": "moderator",
            "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8?d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/12/jeff-atwood",
            "accept_rate": 43
        }
    }, {
        "question_id": 33733,
        "answer_id": 33734,
        "creation_date": 1319994768,
        "last_activity_date": 1319994768,
        "score": 14,
        "is_accepted": true,
        "owner": {
            "user_id": 9752,
            "display_name": "lunboks",
            "reputation": 11504,
            "user_type": "registered",
            "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e73aa0432546c2c3c39dfcf1fa124c09?d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9752/lunboks",
            "accept_rate": 90
        }
    }, {
        "question_id": 33733,
        "answer_id": 38377,
        "creation_date": 1322198871,
        "last_edit_date": 1322200473,
        "last_activity_date": 1322200473,
        "score": 0,
        "is_accepted": false,
        "owner": {
            "user_id": 15257,
            "display_name": "Black Knight",
            "reputation": 1,
            "user_type": "unregistered",
            "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/895d9181500c9c2f28a279c89fd1ab78?d=identicon&r=PG",
            "link": "http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15257/black-knight"
        }
    }],
    "quota_remaining": 9892,
    "quota_max": 10000,
    "has_more": false
}
```

Comment: and it also appears that batching tags together (`battlefield-3;minecraft`) will make this return no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

Note that the `{tags}` field is an AND operation with multiple tags, since most questions on gaming have a single tag this is naturally not going to return many result with multiple tags.

[It does work though](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/85/tags/league-of-legens;money/top-answers?site=gaming).

Comment: While I would love to visit that link, I appear to have been throttled for the next 14.5 hours, despite the fact I haven't made any API requests in the past half hour.

Comment: Duh, I chucked a key on it and it was fine. Thanks.